# DSolve and Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

I was working on this equation to solve and plot it, but I'm little bit confuse?!

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
b = 0.7; a = 1.3; k = -0.002; d = 0.25; 
sol=DSolve[{(2/3)*x*y[x]*Derivative[1][y][x] + a*y[x]^2 - 
Sqrt[3]*d*y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 + k/x^2 - b] + ((a - 2/3)*k)/x^2 - a*b == 0, 
y[1] == 1}, y, x]

Plot[y[x]/.sol, {x, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Probably   `xy[x]` , `ay[x]` and `dh[x]` should be `x y[x]` ,`a y[x]` and `d h[x]`? `h[x]`isn't defined?

Comment: there isn't any h[x] actually only y[x], I did but the solution is not clear!!

Comment: Without knowing `h[x] ` you can't plot the solution!

Comment: There's no h[x] at all, please see again

Comment: `DSolve` cannot solve your ODE, so it returns unevaluated.  Consequently, `y[x]` cannot be plotted.  Try `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok with the modified question ( no `h[x]` anymore) Mathematica isn't able to solve the ode analytically ( `DSolve`).

But numerical solution (`NDSolve`or`NDSolveValue`) is possible:

```
Y = NDSolveValue[{(2/3)*x*y[x]*Derivative[1][y][x] + a*y[x]^2 -Sqrt[3]*d*y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 + k/x^2 - b] + ((a - 2/3)*k)/x^2 -a*b == 0, y[1] == 1}
, y, {x, 1, 10}]


Plot[Y[x], {x, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking if I use this parametric plot how should be look like:

ParametricNDSolve[{(2/3)*x*y[x]*Derivative[1][y][x] + a*y[x]^2 - 
         d*Sqrt[3]*y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 + k/x^2 - b] + (k*(a - 2/3))/
     x^2 - a*b == 0, y[1] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 1, 10}, {b, k, d, a}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[b, k, d, a][x] /. sol, {b, -0.7, -0.69, 0.01}, 
       {k, -0.002, -0.003, -0.001}, {d, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1}, {a, 1, 2, 
    0.5}]], {x, 1, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> All]

Comment: Again don't forget in your differential equation! Try `Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(2/3)*x y[x]*Derivative[1][y][x] + 
     a y[x]^2 - 
     d Sqrt[3]*y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 + k/x^2 - b] + (k*(a - 2/3))/x^2 - 
     a b == 0, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 1, 10}, {b, k, d, a}]`

Comment: ...and try `Plot[Table[
  Y[b, k, d, a][x] , {b, -0.7, -0.69, 
   0.01}, {k, -0.002, -0.003, -0.001}, {d, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1}, {a, 1, 2, 
   0.5}] , {x, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: I did this but it is not running!!

Comment: IAgain I checked my code and it runs (MMA v12.2)

Comment: Again I checked it didn't, mine is (MMA v12.0.0 Mac)

Comment: You could show what you tried?

Comment: Now it is running thanks.

Comment: Ulrich, I'm using this code as well:

Plot3D[Y[x, a, k], {x, 1, 10}, {a, 0.3, 0.7}, {k, -0.0022, -0.002}]

Comment: How can I plot a surface of this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131989/discussion-between-m-s-md-and-ulrich-neumann).